# exportar funcion node en angular 4?

Tags: nodejs, angularjs-2.0

Estimados, necesito procesar un archivo xlsx y parsearlo a json y mi idea es poder hacerlo en la vista con angular 4, encontre una libreria en node el cual hace el proceso (node-xlsx-json) pero nose si pudiera llamarlo desde angular o poder hacer algo ya que la libreria lee el archivo localmente y lo proceso.

```
var xlsx_json = require('../')

xlsx_json({
  input: __dirname + '/interview.xlsx',
  output: __dirname + '/test.json'
}, function(err, result) {
  if(err) {
    console.error(err);
  }else {
    console.log(result);
  }

});
```

O alguna forma de poder realizarlo.

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer un endpoint en el servidor, y conectarte con el desde angular en el cliente. Asi le pasas el xlsl hacia el servidor dejas que el haga todo el trabajo y despues le das la respuesta ( el json ) a angular, para el cliente es un proceso transparente

Tendrias algo asi en el servidor:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const xlsx_json = require('../');

const input = __dirname + '/interview.xlsx';
const output = __dirname + '/test.json';

function getJson(cb) {
    xlsx_json({
        input,
        output,
    }, cb);
}

app.use("/parse-xlsx", (req, res) => {
    const file = req.file;

    fs.writeFile(input, file, (err) => {
        // handle err
        getJson((err, result) => {
            // handle err
            res.send(result);
        });
    });

});
```